# how to transfer data to elastic via logstast and using analyzer?

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash

I have a logstash config file below. Elastic is reading my data as `a` `b` where as i want it to read it as `ab` i found i need to use `not_analyzed` for my `sscat` filed and `max_shingle_size` , `min_shingle_size` for products to get the best result.

Should I use `not_analyzed` for products field as well? Will that give better result?

How should I fill my `my_id_analyzer` to actually use the analyzer on different fields?

How should I connect the template with logstash config file?

```
input{
    file{
    path => "path"
    start_position =>"beginning"

    }
}
filter{
    csv{
    separator => ","
    columns => ["Index", "Category", "Scat", "Sscat", "Products", "Measure", "Price", "Description", "Gst"]
    }
    mutate{convert => ["Index", "float"] }
    mutate{convert => ["Price", "float"] }
    mutate{convert => ["Gst", "float"] }

}
output{
    elasticsearch{
        hosts => "host"
        user => "elastic"
        password => "pass"
        index => "masterdb"
        }

}
```

I also have a template that can do it for all the future files that i upload

```
curl user:pass host:"host" /_template/logstash-id -XPUT -d '{
    "template": "logstash-*",
    "settings" : {
        "analysis": {
            "analyzer": {
                "my_id_analyzer"{

                }
                }
            }
        }
    },
    "mappings": {
             "properties" : {
                "id" : { "type" : "string", "analyzer" : "my_id_analyzer" }
            }
        }

    }'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use "**ignore_above:**" to restrict to a max length along with "**not_analyzed**" while creating mapping so that text doesn't get analyzed.
Declaring type as **keyword** instead of **text** will be other alternative for you.
Regarding the connecting template with logstash, why you need this? Once you have template created on elasticsearch, you can create your index which will follow the created template definition and you can start indexing.

Comment: how should i add not_analyzed in my logstash config file?

Comment: "not_analyzed" should be part of your mapping. So while creating mapping in es, use "not_analyzed" .